# Extracting a subgraph from a graph using JUNG?

Tags: java, algorithm, jung

I have a large graph that I am processing using JUNG. I was wondering if there JUNG provides a way to extract say a 2-hop neighborhood of a vertex (complete with all edges amongst themselves) into a separate graph?

Answer (score 7):

In JUNG 2.0 it is [edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.filters.KNeighborhoodFilter](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/filters/KNeighborhoodFilter.html):

> A filter used to extract the k-neighborhood around one or more root
>   node(s). The k-neighborhood is defined as the subgraph induced by the
>   set of vertices that are k or fewer hops (unweighted shortest-path
>   distance) away from the root node.

Here's how you'd use it (assuming you already have a graph and vertex/edge types):

```
Graph<V, E> graph = // ...
int k = 3; // maximum hops
V startVertex = // ... (pick your starting node)
Filter<V, E> filter = new KNeighborhoodFilter<V, E>(
    startVertex, k, EdgeType.IN_OUT);
Graph<V, E> neighborhood = filter.transform(graph);
```

The `neighborhood` graph will be of the same class as your original graph. You will have to create a new filter for each different start node.

Comment: @Christoph, thank you for posting this sample code, it has helped me greatly. I know this post is four years old, but hey I just came across this answer and is the best one by far. This should be marked as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try `edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.connectivity.KNeighborhoodExtractor`

Comment: That's from the now-very-out-of-date JUNG 1.x.  The above answer is correct.